# Can you compare unstandardized regression coefficients from two separately run models?

Tags: regression

Imagine that you found two studies which did regression analysis of, say, the effects of social distancing on the number of covid cases.

Let's say that in both studies the authors have operationalized the variables in the same way. Let's define social distancing as the lowest distance in cm that a certain individual has to any other person in his/her surroundings. Likewise, the number of covid cases is the nationally reported number of covid cases. Let's say that the first study was done in Sweden, and the other study was done in Spain.

Let's say that in Sweden you obtained the unstandardized regression coefficient B of -0.8, and in Spain -1.64. So in Sweden for every 1 cm increase in social distance, you will have 0.8 less covid cases, and in Spain for every 1 cm distance, you will have 1.64 less covid cases.

Would it thus be justifiable to say that social distancing was double as effective in Spain than in Sweden? Or should exclusively standardized coefficients be used to make this comparison?

For example, social distancing may have from the start higher mean values in Sweden than in Spain. Perhaps it's also possible that Spain has a larger variance of social distancing - perhaps in Sweden everyone likes to keep a larger distance, whereas in Spain, there are more people who prefer a closer distance, but there are also others who like the larger distance. All other combinations of differences in means/variances are possible as well. So then it's possible that, if you reported standardized regression coefficients, the Spanish one wouldn't be double the size of the Swedish one, but they would be the same. In this case, what is the correct conclusion to make? Is social distancing "two times better" in Spain than in Sweden, or are they the same?

Edit: Please do not suggest other ways to parametrize the model in which this comparison could/could not be made (like moderated regression etc.). This question is not about "How to compare regression coefficients...", but just about the validity of comparison of standardized/unstandardized coefficients in the situation which I described.